# how to secure woocommerce downloadable files

Tags: wordpress, download, woocommerce, directory-structure

As the title states I have a question about digital downloadable products through woocommerce.  I am new to web development and wordpress so go easy on me.  I am trying to add a downloadable product where you can't access the file by direct url.  I have set the download type to force download to prevent link sharing but found that I can still access the purchasable files by typing in the direct path Example:

```
example.com/wp-content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/2015/06/examplefile.pdf
```

I have done quite a bit of research but have come up with very few results.  One of the only things that I have found is that I should move the downloadable files outside of the root directory.  I have attempted to do this but then the download links no longer work.  Instead of doing a forced download like normal it redirects to to a page like

```
example.com/home/user/public_html/home/user/downloads/examplefile.pdf
```

So I am thinking woocommerce must not be friendly with the files outside the root directory.  All in all I am out of ideas of what else to try.  Any help or suggestions of how to make this work (having files outside root directory) or other solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a folder outside the public_html directory and upload the files here, you will be safe.

You can find detailed explanations about this topic and how to copy the links of uploaded files in this [blog post](https://www.sellwithwp.com/how-to-create-woocommerce-secure-downloads/).

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a .htaccess file in the woocommerce_uploads folder with
    `deny from all`